# Xfinium PDF: How to auto-resize images

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I'm using the Xfinium PDF library to create PDF documents, programmatically.  I'm importing pictures in with varying sizes that need to be added to the PDFs as pages.  The [DrawImage documentation](https://www.xfiniumpdf.com/help/xfinium.pdf/Xfinium.Pdf.NetStandard%7EXfinium.Pdf.Graphics.PdfGraphics%7EDrawImage(PdfImage,Double,Double,Double,Double).html) states

> If both width and height are negative then the image is scaled automatically to fit the given area and the original aspect ratio is kept.

However, when I try that, I don't see anything on the page.  Must I add the image to a parent container that specifies a height and width? If so, how do I do that?  I was assuming that it would take the height and width of the parent page.  Here's my code snippet:

```cs
var document = new PdfFixedDocument();
using (var imageStream = new FileStream(fileToOpen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var image = new PdfPngImage(imageStream);
    var page = document.Pages.Add();
    page.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, -1, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 2 parameters of DrawImage method specify the size of the area where the image is displayed. 
If you want to cover the whole page but keep the original image aspect ratio you have to call it as follows:

```
page.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, -page.Width, -page.Height);
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops the [XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library.

Comment: Thank you, Mihai!  This is probably something good to throw in your Xfinium API docs, as well, as others may have the same use-case as mine.